# How do I reverse scaling of entire data frame?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scaling

When I was scaling each column separately reversing the process was easy. Example:

```
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train)
reverse=sc_X.inverse_transform(X_train)
```

when I have to scale entire data frame, its easy to scale it in one line of code by:

```
dfv = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df)
```

But how to reverse this process? I mean how do I change the code below, so that the graph has original scale but correct cluster category color? Especially that dfv is not a data frame anymore as seem that scaling changed it to an array?

```
# Model
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 5, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 15)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(dfv)
# 2D Visualisation after clustering
X = dfv
df.columns.tolist()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='white')
ax.set_facecolor((0.898, 0.898, 0.898))

plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 0, 0], X[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 20, c = 'red', label = 'Cluster1')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 1, 0], X[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 20, c = 'blue', label = 'Cluster2')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 2, 0], X[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 20, c = 'limegreen', label = 'Cluster3')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 3, 0], X[y_kmeans == 3, 1], s = 20, c = 'magenta', label = 'Cluster4')
plt.scatter(X[y_kmeans == 4, 0], X[y_kmeans == 4, 1], s = 20, c = 'blueviolet', label = 'Cluster5')

ax.set_title('Features after clustering')
ax.set_xlabel(df.columns[0])
ax.set_ylabel(df.columns[1])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: But you have original DataFrame. Why do you need to revert something? Did you try "X = df"

Comment: because to plot the points I need 3 pieces of information: original x coordinate, original y co-ordinate and cluster label assigned after scaling. How can I do that?

Comment: Thank you Danylo Baibak, I have been silly - I just added cluster labels to original frame - you were right